# Flash video slow/not playing

Tags: jquery, flash, video-streaming

I have a Flash video playing as part of a jQuery slideshow. But it seems not to be autoplaying successfully, and is loading very slowly. It usually loads on refresh, but not when someone first hits the page.

The video is at *link removed as it will be outdated shortly - we're moving to production; besides, the problem is solved*.

Is my embed code wrong (surely, I'm missing something)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The 'problem' was poor connectivity, less obvious in a a rush to deadline but perfectly obvious now. Doh!